# Jquery SlideToggle presist state after browser back button

Tags: jquery, opera, slidetoggle

I have a DIV that slideToggles no problem. It reveals some additional options to the visitor. Once the form is submit, if for example an error is encountered the visitor presses their browser back button to rectify. The div with all the additional options is not in the state is was last left, rather it is collapsed. Any ideas how I can prevent this?

```
    $("#sendChange").click(function () {
                          $("#sendSpec").slideToggle("slow");
                        if($('#sendWhen').html() == 'IMMEDIATLY'){
                           $('#sendWhen').html('AS SPECIFIED');
                        }else{
                           $('#sendWhen').html('IMMEDIATLY');
                        }
                        return false;
});




<div class="fcenter stdBox line25" style="margin-bottom:0px;" id="emlOptions">
<div>
     <label class="lab">Send email: </label><span id="sendWhen" class="blue">IMMEDIATLY</span> <a href="#" id="sendChange">[change]</a>
</div>
<div style="display:none" id="sendSpec">
    <label for="userTz" class="lab">Timezone: </label><select name="userTz" id="userTz" onchange="tzChange(this.value)" class="field" >
<option value="Pacific/Apia">(GMT-11:00) Midway Island, Samoa</option>
<option value="Pacific/Honolulu">(GMT-10:00) Hawaii</option>
...
</select>  <br />

<label for="delayTimeDate" class="lab">Time & Date: </label><input type="text" class="field" name="delayTimeDate" id="datepicker" />
<br /><br />
</div>
```

So I tried adding a hidden text field which worked in FF but not Opera. Opera forgets the hidden field values but not text field ones so I wrapped the text field in a display:none div which remembers the value ok but javascript fires before the formfield has its value updated by the Opera browser. Here is the code:

```
function sendSpec () {
                          $("#sendSpec").slideToggle("slow");
                        if($('#sendWhen').html() == 'IMMEDIATLY'){
                           $('#sendWhen').html('AS SPECIFIED');
                           $('#sendWhenState').val('1');
                        }else{
                           $('#sendWhen').html('IMMEDIATLY');
                           $('#sendWhenState').val('0');
                        }}

$("#sendChange").click(function () {
                     sendSpec();
                    return false;
});
if($('#sendWhenState').val() == 1){
    sendSpec();
}
```

HTML is the same but with the added formfield

```
<div style="display:none"><input type="text" id="sendWhenState" value="0" /></div>
```

I don't like this but couldn't find another way. the above is the same just added a timeout to the if sendWhenState == 1 so that Opera will have updated the fields before I check their value like so:

```
setTimeout(function(){
                    if($('#sendWhenState').val() == 1){
                       sendSpec();
                    }
         },1000);
```

I'm new here, should I have answered my own question or was I right to edit the question with the solution I came up with?

Comment: Post some code. You can set a cookie

Comment: I'd rather avoid using cookies for this. How about a hidden form field instead?

Comment: I tried with a hidden field, seems to work in FF at least. Anyone aware of any cross browser issues to this method?

Comment: Post the code on jsfiddle or something

Comment: I've posted above, I don't like linking to external content in case it is removed at a later date rendering this question useless to anyone else.

Comment: Its perfectly acceptable to link to jsfiddle.

Comment: As is posting above. jsfiddle aside any comments for the question itself?

Comment: This is a case for cookies. Trying to manipulate a weird Firefox quirk across browsers is strange.

Comment: Normally I'd agree, however Europe screwed up the usefulness of cookies by implementing law that requires the website to ask permission before saving any cookies  http://www.cookielaw.org/ Firefox works fine, it's Opera that acts strange wrt hidden fields and repopulating history/cache when you click back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a hidden text field which worked in FF but not Opera. Opera forgets the hidden field values but not text field ones so I wrapped the text field in a display:none div which remembers the value ok but javascript fires before the formfield has its value updated by the Opera browser. Here is the code:

```
function sendSpec () {
                          $("#sendSpec").slideToggle("slow");
                        if($('#sendWhen').html() == 'IMMEDIATLY'){
                           $('#sendWhen').html('AS SPECIFIED');
                           $('#sendWhenState').val('1');
                        }else{
                           $('#sendWhen').html('IMMEDIATLY');
                           $('#sendWhenState').val('0');
                        }}

$("#sendChange").click(function () {
                     sendSpec();
                    return false;
});
if($('#sendWhenState').val() == 1){
    sendSpec();
}
```

HTML is the same but with the added formfield

```
<div style="display:none"><input type="text" id="sendWhenState" value="0" /></div>
```

I don't like this but couldn't find another way. the above is the same just added a timeout to the if sendWhenState == 1 so that Opera will have updated the fields before I check their value like so:

```
setTimeout(function(){
                    if($('#sendWhenState').val() == 1){
                       sendSpec();
                    }
         },1000);
```